# How to show error message to specific div after maxLengh or required validation failed with template validation?

Tags: javascript, angular

I understand that Angular can do validation by html template and output validation errors

However what if I have a single`div` on top of component html and an `errorMessage` attribute in the component class, and desire to output all the validation error in that single div, how to achieve such goal?

```
  <div class="errorMessage">...</div>

  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name" #name [(ngModel)]="account.name"
         name="name" (click)="clearErrors()" maxlength="40" required>

  <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)">

    <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
      Account name cannot be empty.    <-- like to show this msg on div.errorMessage
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="name.errors.maxlength">
      Account name maximum length exceeded. <-- like to show this msg on div.errorMessage
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move error section into the desired message container.

```
  <div class="errorMessage">
        <ng-container *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)">
            <ng-container *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                Account name cannot be empty. </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="name.errors.maxlength">
                Account name maximum length exceeded.
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name" #name 
           [(ngModel)]="account.name"
             name="name" (click)="clearErrors()" 
            maxlength="40" required>
```